# Cannot redirect to merchant site after successful payPal payment , because of the Content Security Policy javascript error

Tags: paypal, coldfusion-10, content-security-policy

I made the payment successfully on payPal using a simple html form.

My html form does not have any meta tag for Content Security Policy definition. Even my app server did not configure it.

After payment , while clicking on the Redirect To Merchant button it does not allow me to redirect to merchant website throwing java script error as below.

> util.js:154 Refused to send form data to
>   'https://www.example.com/template.cfm?CFID=698678&CFTOKEN=89f9801a2498f866-D630B2AC-5056-A81A-CD857156F08E0E19'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "form-action 'self' https://*.paypal.com
>   https://*.cardinalcommerce.com".

Comment: I have the same problem - Please update when you got a fix! :)

Comment: figure out where you're loading `util.js`.  Perhaps it's being loaded with the stuff from PayPal?